# ValueError: The parameter 'aux_logits' expected value True but got False instead

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network, transfer-learning

I am following a Pytorch tutorial for caption generation in which, inceptionv3 is used and aux_logits are set to False. But when I followed the same approach, I am getting this error ValueError: The parameter 'aux_logits' expected value True but got False instead. Why it's expecting True when I have passed False? My Pytorch version is 2.0.0

```
def __init__(self, embed_size, trainCNN=False):
    super(encoderCNN, self).__init__()
    self.trainCNN = trainCNN
    self.inception = models.inception_v3(weights=models.Inception_V3_Weights.DEFAULT, aux_logits=False)
    self.inception.fc = nn.Linear(self.inception.fc.in_features, embed_size)
    self.dropout= nn.Dropout(0.5)
    self.relu = nn.ReLU()
```

And also quite couldn't understand the purpose of aux_logits. Is it related to auxiliary classifiers in inceptionv3?

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug when loading inception wights without `auxlogits` set to True. Yes, you are right, auxlogits related to the auxilary classifiers wether to include it or not. You can keep `auxlogits` True and just use the first output of the model
https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/inception-v3-is-not-working-very-well/38296/3